# Reset/reload fragment container

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I reset or reload a fragment container, to make it empty.
I have a master detail view and I want to reset the detail container to empty on a menu item click.This works in some cases and does not in some.

```
 NullFragment fragment = new NullFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.item_detail_container,
 fragment);
 int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
 fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(count, 0);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please document, in which cases it does not work.

Comment: you don't reset the container. you need to to reset the fragment inside the container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you simply remove the fragment from it.

For example do something like

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_container)).commit();
```

this will `remove` the fragment from the `your_container` holding it.

This gets the fragment currently present in your_container

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_container)
```

and this remove the fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

**EDIT**

Also sometimes it is useful to ensure all transactions are performed and finished, this can be done by using

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: What if I have a view pager?

Comment: @maňish I didn't try with a view pager up to now.