# How do I reset fragment in View

Tags: android, android-fragments, reset

I have problem. How do I reset fragment in view or adapter?

I want view click -> data change -> view finish-> fragment reset

It is doing:

```
public class CustomView extends View{

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     switch (which) {
       case 1: {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Fragment fragment = new Z_Hello();
                    FragmentManager manager = fragment.getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.pager, new Z_Hello());
                    ft.commit();

                    }
              }
  }
```

and do it too but both error

```
Fragment frg = new Z_Hello(); 
frg = frg.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager); 
final FragmentTransaction ft = frg.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.detach(frg); ft.attach(frg); ft.commit();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset/reload fragment container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268880/reset-reload-fragment-container)

Comment: DO NOT do anything in onDraw! As the name suggests, it's for drawing only. It may be invoked many times a second. I'm pretty sure you don't need to create a new instance of anonymous class (the listener) multiple times a second. Do it somewhere else once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to carry out such a code in onDraw - the first way to get the brakes.
The easiest way is to disconnect and reconnect the fragment:

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: thanks, this class extend view carry out code come error and what is Your_Fragment_TAG?