# How to refresh my fragment when i change the date from date picker

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to refresh my fragment to show the current data but it is too slow to change the data. So my question is how can I change it as fast as I get the data, the changes should be fast and  the fragment should be on its first instance or you can say on 1st fragment

```
public class PlazaDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static ArrayList<String> plazaList;
    ViewPager vpPager;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TextView actionBarTitle,actionBarDate;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    int year,month,day;

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final ArrayList<String> plazaList;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<String> plazaList) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.plazaList=plazaList;
            Log.e("PLazalist",plazaList.toString());
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return plazaList.size();
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlazaListDetailsFragment.newInstance(0,plazaList.get(position));

        }

    }

    MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    PlazaDetails plazaDetails;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plaza_details);

       plazaDetails = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("PLAZA");

        plazaList = new ArrayList<>();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tollConnectPlazaDetailsToolBar);

         actionBarTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.plazaName) ;
         actionBarDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateText) ;
       ImageButton calendarImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.calanderImage) ;
        ImageButton backArrowButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backArrowButton) ;

            //calendarDilog  view...///
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        String stringMonth  = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());

        String date = String.format("%d %s,%d",day,stringMonth,year);
        Log.e(" Todays Date :",date);



        actionBarDate.setText(date);
        actionBarTitle.setText(plazaDetails.getPlazaName());


        //plazaList = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = TollConnectLiteApplication.userPrfrences.getString(TollConnectLiteConstants.BASE_URL,null)+"Plaza/GetGraph?PlazaID="+plazaDetails.getPlazaId()+"&Shift_Date="+day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
        Log.e("Url",url);
        new PlazaListAsyncTask().execute(url);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),plazaList);
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

        calendarImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datepicker();
            }
        });

        backArrowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

// handling Datepicker event................
    public void datepicker(){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.e("DatePicker","INside calander button click");
        datePickerDialog  = new DatePickerDialog(this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        calendar.setTime( new Date(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth));
                        String month  = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
                        String selectedDate = String.format("%d %s,%d",dayOfMonth,month,year);
                        Log.e(" Todays Date :",selectedDate);
                        actionBarDate.setText(selectedDate);
                        String url = TollConnectLiteApplication.userPrfrences.getString(TollConnectLiteConstants.BASE_URL,null)+"Plaza/GetGraph?PlazaID="+plazaDetails.getPlazaId()+"&Shift_Date="+dayOfMonth+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+year;
                        Log.e("Url",url);
                        new PlazaListAsyncTask().execute(url);
                        onResume();
                    }
                },year,month,day);

      datePickerDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // API 5+ solution
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapterViewPager.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class PlazaListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(PlazaDetailsActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.e("Text","Inside doInBackground");
            try {
                String stringUrl = params[0];
                URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
                URLConnection connection =  url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                return inputStream;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            super.onPostExecute(inputStream);

            Log.e("Text","Inside doInBackground");

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader Rreader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = Rreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String jsonResponse = sb.toString();

            jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replaceAll("\\\\","");
            Log.e("json",jsonResponse);

            jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replace("\"{","{");
            Log.e("json",jsonResponse);
            jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replace("}\"","}");
            Log.e("json",jsonResponse);

            plazaList.clear();
            if (plazaList.isEmpty()){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Section");

                    for (int i=0 ;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

                        DetailsActivityPlazaObject object = new DetailsActivityPlazaObject();
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        plazaList.add(jsonObject1.toString());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.e("PLazalist",plazaList.toString());
            adapterViewPager.notifyDataSetChanged();

            onResume();
            dialog.hide();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try referring this thread,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268880/reset-reload-fragment-container

Comment: where are you refreshing it now ?