# Fragment Error when moving the same screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

https://github.com/MobileSeoul/2017seoul-18

1. I brought open source from Github.
   But, this code was designed to push only one button at a time.
2. So, as soon as I started, I changed 4 information to appear on the screen.

[image]

```
     @Override
     public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         String[] urls = {queryUrlFsn, queryasthmaWho, querybrainWho, queryskinWho};

    if (checkInternet() == true) {
        INTERNET_STATE = true;

        thread(urls[0], date, 0);
        new addThread(fsnIndex, "Food Poisoning Index", value[0], FSN_DIVIDE_VALUE, R.drawable.fsn, showDateTime(showDate)).start();

        thread(urls[1], date, 1);
        new addThread(asthmaWhoIndex, "Asthma lung disease possible index", value[1], WINTERLIFE_DIVIDE_VALUE, R.drawable.asthmawho, showDateTime(showDate)).start();

        thread(urls[2], date, 2);
        new addThread(brainWhoIndex, "Stroke index", value[2], WINTERLIFE_DIVIDE_VALUE, R.drawable.brainwho, showDateTime(showDate)).start();

        thread(urls[3], date, 3);
        new addThread(skinWhoIndex, "Skin disease potential index", value[3], WINTERLIFE_DIVIDE_VALUE, R.drawable.skinwho, showDateTime(showDate)).start();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Network not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

---

https://youtu.be/NuxS6MH55oA

↑ However, when moving from screen A back to screen A, there was a problem that the app was shutting down.

When I checked it, I did not have any problem when I removed the 4 pieces of information displayed on the screen A by clicking on the "trash can picture" and then moved to the screen A again.

---

So, in order to initialize the screen when I switch the screen, I did googleing.
I put the code presented in the stack overflow in the if / else statement below.

[Reset/reload fragment container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268880/reset-reload-fragment-container)

[image]

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    MosquitoFragment mosquitoFragment = new MosquitoFragment();
    WeatherFragment weatherFragment = new WeatherFragment();
    ExpressionFragment expressionFragment = new ExpressionFragment();
    AirFragment airFragment = new AirFragment();
    int id = item.getItemId();



    if (id == R.id.nav_weather) {
        // I inserted this point.
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, weatherFragment);
    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_mosquito) {
        // I inserted this point.
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, mosquitoFragment);
    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_expression) {
        // I inserted this point.
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, expressionFragment);
    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_air) {
        // I inserted this point.
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, airFragment);
    }

    transaction.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

---

However, when I move from A screen to A screen again, an error still occurs. How do we solve it? If I can not solve this problem, I will not fix this open source.

---

Error Code:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: kr.cds.jisulife, PID: 8226
              java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
                  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:611)
                  at kr.cds.jisulife.BrainWhoIndex.getGradeToString(BrainWhoIndex.java:36)
                  at kr.cds.jisulife.WeatherFragment$ListViewAdapter.getView(WeatherFragment.java:452)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
                  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1326)
                  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1233)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```