# Reset/Restart everything in a fragment on button click

Tags: android, kotlin

In another fragment I want to remove everything or reset them and repopulate it with new values. This is achieved in a different fragment with a button click. Maybe there is a better way to do this so I will put my code in the question.

The values in Fragment A is populated using a ViewModel in Fragment B:

Sending my data to Fragment B to A:

```
 startButton.setOnClickListener { v ->
            Log.d("Hur", activity!!.supportFragmentManager.fragments.size.toString())
            val spinnerVal = sizeSpinner.selectedItem.toString().toInt()
            val map = HashMap<String, Any>()
            wordList.sortByDescending { it.length }
            Log.d("Tag", wordList.toString())
            map["words"] = wordList
            map["rowSize"] = spinnerVal
            map["columnSize"] = spinnerVal
            loaded++
            map["loaded"] = loaded
            gameData?.data?.postValue(map)
            (activity as MainActivity).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(0)
        }
```

I am retrieving the values in Fragment A using a ViewPagerListener:

Fragment A - OnCreateView:

```
val pager = (activity as MainActivity).getViewPager()
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Inside")
                    activity?.let {
                        Log.d("Tag", "Hello World!")
                        val gameData = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(GameData::class.java)
                        observeInput(gameData)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

observeInput:

```
      gameData.data.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let {
                words = it["words"] as ArrayList<String>
                columnSize = it["columnSize"] as Int
                rowSize = it["rowSize"] as Int
                Log.d("yes", "Starting Game")
                if(rowSize != 0 && columnSize != 0 && !words.isEmpty() && !loaded) {
                    Log.d("inside", "yes")
                    wordGrid = Array(rowSize) { Array(columnSize) { "" } }
                    findLocations()
                    initLayouts()
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: You mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268880/reset-reload-fragment-container

Comment: I am using a viewpager and I have tried this solution

Comment: When I remove the fragment it doesn't go into the activity.let